# Unexpected behavior of `Exponent`

Tags: bugs, algebraic-manipulation

Fixed in **Version 14.0**

---

According to [`Exponent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exponent.html):

- `Exponent[expr, form]` gives the maximum power with which `form` appears in the expanded form of `expr`.
- `Exponent[expr, form, h]` applies `h` to the set of exponents with which `form` appears in `expr`.
- The default taken for `h` is `Max`.

So `Exponent[..., …, Max]` is equivalent to `Exponent[..., …]`.
But how to explain the following output?

```
In[1]:= Exponent[x, Sqrt[x]]

Out[1]= 2

In[2]:= Exponent[x, Sqrt[x], Max]

Out[2]= 1

In[3]:= Exponent[Sqrt[x], Sqrt[x], Defer]

              1
Out[3]= Defer[-]
              2
```

Isn't this a bug?

Comment: It seems weird, indeed. For example, you can use `List` as the 3rd argument to get all the exponents. But `Exponent[x, Sqrt[x]]` gives `2` and `Exponent[x, Sqrt[x], List]` gives `{1}`.

Comment: The documentation says under Possible Issues that Exponent is purely syntactical and does no analysis.

Comment: @RolandF If so, shouldn't `Exponent[x, Sqrt[x]]` return `0` (instead of `2`)? And shouldn't `Exponent[Sqrt[x], Sqrt[x], Identity]` return `1` (rather than `1/2`)?

Comment: By experiment,  Exponent[x^a, x^b] works reasonably with numbers as exponents of symbols, but not with exponent symbols. Even specifying  everything] as positive integers  or expecting simplifications as in Exponent[(1-x^2)/(1+x),x]  returns input.  Using a non-symbol expression as variable in polynomial reduction  may be termed 'abuse of powers'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in Version 14.0, now `Exponent[Sqrt[x], Sqrt[x], Defer]` returns `1/2`

[image]